# Multi-tenant Azure dynamic wildcard CName

Tags: azure, multi-tenant, cname

I am trying to create a multitenant Azure website which is a way for people to sign up and get their sub-domains. I have followed the instructions in here (http://www.stratospher.es/blog/post/wildcard-subdomains-in-windows-azure) and manage to get all *.mydomain.com CNAME to mydomain.azurewebsites.net according to (http://www.digwebinterface.com/)

Here is the problem 
if I go to tenant1.mydomain.com I'll get the 404 server error. However if I log in to Azure and go to my website Manage custom domains and add the tenant1.mydomain.com then everything would work fine.

The idea behind the wildcard is I can add tenant pragmatically/dynamically. Is there anyway to automated this process or add a wildcard in the azure Manage custom domains. Is there any difference between app cloud service and website?

Thanks for your help

**Update**
I end up using cloud services instead of websites. You don't need to configure the custom domain names in the control panel anymore. Just simply point cname and your good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the use of Amazon Route 53 to configure the domain mapping in Azure, it seems that there are options.

Please refer the following links

1. [Sub domain mapping in windows azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120172/sub-domain-mapping-in-windows-azure)
2. [Add custom Domain to azurewebsite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362791/add-custom-domain-to-azurewebsite)