# Add custom Domain to azurewebsite

Tags: azure, cname

my domain provider does not have CNAME interface (http://nic.do) they told me that they only works with DNS but all the documentation that i get from Azure is adding a CNAME.

how can i add custom domain name to my azure shared webssite??

Comment: Can you get a different DNS provider?

Comment: well i only can get .do domain in nic.do (Dominican Republic domain name provider)

Comment: You need a DNS hoster/provider.I know it sounds a little strange to use another service, but I use Route 53 by Amazon AWS for my DNS hosting, it costs about $0.50 USD/month.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, let me try that

Comment: Hello, i create my AWS account and set an Route 53, i put the NS address that amazon give me in the DNS of my domain, and then create the CNAME to from www.myDomain.do to AzureWsName.azurewebsites.net

but when i try to enter to my url it shows:

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Comment: also, in http://www.digwebinterface.com/ it show that piezas.do and www.piezas.do are pointing to my azurewebsite but when i try to add Domain to azure it says **The DNS record for 'piezas.do' that points to 'Piezas.azurewebsites.net' could not be located. If you want to configure an A record, you must first create a CNAME record with your DNS provider for 'awverify.piezas.do' that points to 'awverify.Piezas.azurewebsites.net'. First allow the resource record to propagate, and then create the A record.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As   Jeff Wilcox said: i solved this problem using AWS Route 53, just had to configure the DNS on my domain to the ones that Route 53 gives to me and then configure the R53 using Windows Azure instructions.